# Windows 10 time-controlled power settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, energy-saving, energy

Is there a way to configure Windows that it uses different energy profiles at different times?

For example: Between 8:00 PM and 6:00 AM I want Windows to use the "Power saver" profile and between 6:00 AM and 8:00 PM I want Windows to use either the "Balanced" profile, the "High performance" profile or the "Ultimate performance" profile.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can achieve this with the Scheduler, with a schedule set to run at specific times to load in a different profile. Have a look at `powercfg` command line, specifically the `/setactive` flag.

Comment: There also used to be a freeware program called SetPower (for Windows 7), however it does not seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Run `powercfg /list` in the CLI to get a list of profile ID's. Lets say for this example it returns

```
ABC123 (Balanced)
XYZ789 (Ultra)
```

Create a new scheduled task to run at 8pm daily, with the action `powercfg /setactive ABC123`

Create a second scheduled task to run at 6am daily, with the action `powercfg /setactive XYZ789`

This does lock you in to one profile though. There's no way (as far as I am aware) to prompt you to choose from x of y plans (in your case, 1 of the 3 plans you mention)